# Replace the div content with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to replace the div content dynamically ajax call.Following is the code which i tried.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a  class="reply_doc" data-doc_value="1">111</a><br>
<a href="#" class="reply_doc" data-doc_value="2">222</a><br>
<a href="#" class="reply_doc" data-doc_value="3">333</a><br>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".reply_doc").click(function () {
    var a = $("a.reply_doc").attr("data-doc_value"); //<-- Add this
    if (a != "") {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sortingajax.php",
        data: "doc_reply=" + a,
        success: function (b) {
            alert(a+' ok. '+b)
            $('#ResponseDiv').html(b);
            console.log(b);
        }
    });
  }
 });
});
</script>
<div id='ResponseDiv'>
        This is a div to hold the response.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

sortingajax.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$countsql='SELECT * FROM XML WHERE';
$countsql1=mysql_query($countsql);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($countsql1);  
$countArray2=array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($countsql1)) {
    // Append to the array
    $countArray2[] = $row;
    //echo $row['PID']."<BR />";
}

?>
<?php
foreach($countArray2 as $array)
{
?>
        <div class="search">

        I am in US.
        </div>
        <?php

 $i++; } ?>
```

In the first page.when i click on a link and there it will call sortingajax.php with ajax call.After that it should replace ResponseDiv content with sortingajax.php content.

Please tell me where i am doing wrong as i m not that aware of ajax calls...

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly. It makes it much easier for you and others to read.

Comment: You're not returning anything, are you?.. Moreover, have you tried console.log(b)? is it even set?

Comment: `<title />` tag missing, `$("a.reply_doc").attr("data-doc_value");` should be `$("a.reply_doc").data("doc_value");`, afaik, `data` should be in `json` format and you should also return json and create the content instead of inserting html, deprecated `mysql` lib used, MySQL statement is invalid.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan-I will take care next time.

Comment: @DanFromGermany-how can i return json and replace it with div content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax code looks correct, the php code on the other hand looks a bit wrong. First off, stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` api and switch to either `PDO` or `mysqli`.
The `mysql_*` api is deprecated and will be removed from php soon.

```
SELECT * FROM XML WHERE
```

^ This is not a correct mysql query, you need to add something to check for after the `WHERE` keyword, or just skip it if you want to select all the rows from the `XML` table.
Due to this query failing, you will not have any data to print, and your `ResponseDiv` should be empty after the call has been done.

Comment: Happy to help. Please mark answer as correct if that was what you needed! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have leave query partial. please fill condition after `WHERE` otherwise remove WHERE from query in **sortingajax.php**

1. You are sending data in var **doc_reply** but you are not used this variable in **sortingajax.php** file.
2. Why are you used two different loops ?
3. Mysql is deprecated. Use **[Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    follow this Simple Example Of add or remove element using ajax/jQuery
```

-Example:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>     
<div id="files">
             <div>
                <input type="text" name="description[]" class="form-control" placeholder="File Description"/> <br/>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" /> 
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
    <div style="margin: 5px; cursor: pointer;" class="text-center">
             <a id="addFile"><strong>+ Add Another File</strong></a>
    </div> 

    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#addFile").click(function() {
                 $("#files").append("<div>Your Contain</div>");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

if you want to remove element.. then use this simple code
$("#Id Of Element").remove()

Comment: Thanks fr ur help.but my div content which i want to replace is quite big.Its ok.but it worked other way quite easily...