# Get DIV content using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm able to get the result from the second page, but the thing is that I'm getting everything that is in the HTML output, I only want certain parts of it... 
I'm already about 1K of code lines using jQuery, and JavaScript, and by loading the whole page from the ajax it just break the whole app... 
The content from the secondPage is dynamic and it has javascript and jquery, which I don't need that for the end result but I do to get the process... so..

secondpage.php is just a form base on my first page, so my "Ajax" is in the "main_page.php" like this...

```
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
    var xmlhttp=false;
    try{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)    {
        try{
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1){
                xmlhttp=false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
function getNenes(medi) {
    var strURL ="secondpage.php?id="+medi;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();
    if (req) {
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML=req.responseText;
            }
        }
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }
}
```

this is a functional script if you want to use it for whatever you want... 
Now on my secondpage.php this is what I have.... sort of...

```
<?php
include ('connect.php');
// lets make a header
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
 // lets make a query and all that is need
 // to fetch the information based on the ID #
} else {
 // lets add a header 
 header ("Location: you_are_not_allow.php");
}
?>
<!-- let put our HTML -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> <!-- Required -->

<div id="copy">
 <!-- everything that is here is what we want -->
 <!-- form input's, div's, span's ...etc -->
 <!-- I have a few foreach for input's array -->
 <!-- Anything else is useless for the main page -->
</div>
 <!-- Now I need to put the info for each input that I might get -->
 <!-- for that I'm using array's -->
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
foreach ($m as $n) {
echo '$("#d_'.$c.'").children("option[value=\''.$d->ds.'\']").prop("selected",true);';
    $c++;
}
echo '</script>';
?>
```

So, until this point everything is working "just fine", the thing is that when I get the result from the secondpage.php I don't want the < script > only what is inside the first div with the ID copy...

Things I don't use and cause conflicts on main_page.php are:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    foreach ($m as $n) {
    echo '$("#d_'.$c.'").children("option[value=\''.$d->ds.'\']").prop("selected",true);';
        $c++;
    }
    echo '</script>';
    ?>
```

So how can I just fetch what is inside my `<div id = "copy">`?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076982/replace-the-div-content-with-ajax?rq=1

Comment: it actually work the same way as to what I have, it gives me the whole HTML from the secondpage.php which is not what I want... but thank you.

Comment: When you make an AJAX request to another page it always returns the entire page, that is how it is designed. What you could do is send the PHP page some info and have it use that info to echo out only what you're looking for. We have used that technique many time when returning an entire page was too unwieldy.

Comment: That's what I have, I only echo what I need even on the < script type > only what I need, the thing is that because I'm echoing the < script > as needed it gets render all together with want I need... I also concatenate some html just to make sure I only output what I need, but the result is the same, thank you.

Comment: I wonder... I have this on my ajax... `document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML=req.responseText;` which is what is use to display the result on the main_page.php ... can I get the html to a varible? ... then just search for what I actually need? ...

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the inside of this tag with JQuery
`$("#copy")` to select the tag.
`$("#copy").html()` to get what's inside